# Method cannot be called due to unsatisfied trait bounds

Tags: rust

I'm getting a "method cannot be called on `TermWriter<&mut impl CursorPos>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds" error here:

**input.rs:**

```
pub fn get_input(
    input_keys: impl Iterator<Item = Result<Key, io::Error>>,
    stdout: &mut impl CursorPos,
) -> Result<Input, InputError> {
    let input = String::new();
    let mut term_writer = TermWriter::new(input, stdout); // HERE

    for key in input_keys {
        match key.unwrap() {
            Key::Esc => return Ok(Input::Exit),
            Key::Left => term_writer.left()?,  // AND HERE
            _ => {}
        }

        // stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }

    let input = term_writer.input.trim().to_owned();

    Ok(Input::Text(input))
}
```

I'm confused. As you can see, `TermWriter`'s `stdout` field should implement the `CursorPos` trait:

**term_writer.rs**

```
use crate::input::{Input, InputError};
use std::io::Write;
use termion::cursor::DetectCursorPos;

struct Position {
    x: u16,
    y: u16,
}

// CursorPos

pub trait CursorPos {
    fn write_fmt(&mut self, s: &str) -> Result<(), std::io::Error>;
    fn cursor_position(&self) -> Result<(u16, u16), std::io::Error>;
}

// Stdout

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Stdout;

impl CursorPos for Stdout {
    fn write_fmt(&mut self, s: &str) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn cursor_position(&self) -> Result<(u16, u16), std::io::Error> {
        Ok((2, 2))
    }
}

// TermWriter

pub struct TermWriter<T: CursorPos> {
    pub input: String,
    stdout: T,
    cursor_pos: Position,
}

impl<T: CursorPos> TermWriter<T> {
    pub fn new(input: String, stdout: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            input,
            stdout,
            cursor_pos: Position { x: 1, y: 2 },
        }
    }

    pub fn left(&mut self) -> Result<(), InputError> {
        let cursor_pos = self.stdout.cursor_position()?;

        self.cursor_pos.x = cursor_pos.0;

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

And I'm already stating that here (in `input.rs`):

```
stdout: &mut impl CursorPos
```

What's the problem, and how to fix it?

This is the original compile error (sorry, it had to be a photo because I don't know how to replicate the formatting with text).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the `impl CursorPos` in your `get_input()` function with a generic parameter `T`, we can quickly see the problem:

```rust
pub fn get_input<T: CursorPos>(
    input_keys: impl Iterator<Item = Result<Key, io::Error>>,
    stdout: &mut T,
) -> Result<Input, InputError> {
    let input = String::new();
    let mut term_writer = TermWriter::new(input, stdout);

    // ...
}
```

Now we see the problem: we aren't passing a value `T` that implements `CursorPos`, we're passing a value `&mut T` for some `T` that implements `CursorPos`! That means the `term_writer` we're creating is actually of type `TermWriter<&mut T>`, and `&mut T` does not implement `CursorPos`.

This can be fixed by changing the definition of `TermWriter` to store an `&mut T` as well:

```rust
pub struct TermWriter<'a, T: CursorPos> {
    pub input: String,
    stdout: &'a mut T,
    cursor_pos: Position,
}
```

And change the definition of `TermWriter::new()` accordingly:

```rust
impl<'a, T: CursorPos> TermWriter<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(input: String, stdout: &'a mut T) -> Self {
        Self {
            input,
            stdout,
            cursor_pos: Position { x: 1, y: 2 },
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now the types are compatible, and we no longer have compilation errors.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I've been stuck with this for a long time. I didn't know `T` and `&mut T` would be considered two different types.